# Why is it that Beerus and Whis know Frieza but not Buu?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

It's a known fact that Beerus was asleep for 38/39 years.

When he wakes up, Whis tells him that a Saiyan defeated Frieza.

I know 39 years is a long time however Buu was also on rampage throughout the universe way before that (fighting the Supreme Kaihous and so on).

How come they know about Frieza and don't know about Buu?

Comment: Well, more importantly, how come they don't know Buu despite the fight between Goku and Buu happens after Frieza's defeat. And what about Cell?

Comment: Cell is just an "earthling" villain

Comment: @SakuraiTomoko Probably for the same reason Beerus doesn't know about Goku. They're insignificant to him and don't interfere with his role as  the god of destruction.

Comment: Dragon Ball Super has some giant plot holes in this area.  Most notably, about how Old Kai has to tell the Supreme Kai who Beerus is despite the fact that Beerus is active every 50 years, and Supreme Kai fought Buu a really really long time ago(most definitely more than 50 years ago)

Comment: Even I have this question all the time and am desperately looking for this answer. Why Beerus did not kill Buu when Buu was on rampage? Krikara said, "*It's possible that Beerus didn't need to seek Buu for a challenge if he was already stronger than him.*" But even if Buu was not a challenge, he though was a threat to him. If Buu kills the Supreme Kai, Beerus dies too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Dragon Ball Super, as well as Battle of the Gods, Beerus did not know about Majin Buu. The manga has not given a definitive answer as to why they don't know each other, but we can narrow down the potential answers.

In an interview, Akira Toriyama has stated that contrary to Supreme Kai's statement about Bibidi creating Buu, Buu has actually been around since the beginning of time. Bibidi just knew how to wake up Buu from his long slumber.

We also know that gods aren't born as gods in Dragon Ball. They obtain the god title after training and fulfilling their duties. Thus we know that Buu existed before Beerus became a god.

This means that Beerus not knowing Buu can be attributed to any of the possibilities below -

1. Beerus and Buu never met each other - possible due to the excessive amount of time they spend asleep.
2. Beerus might have met Buu, but in kid Buu form. He has never seen Mr. Buu before.
3. There was no reason to meet. Beerus destroys planets to maintain the balance of the universe. With Buu also destroying planets, he essentially did Beerus' job for him.

We also know that Beerus sealed Old Supreme Kai into that sword. During that time, Buu was also asleep, so there was no chance for Beerus to meet Buu during that time.

We should also note that Old Kai described Buu as more evil than Beerus while Beerus was more powerful than Buu. It's possible that Beerus didn't need to seek Buu for a challenge if he was already stronger than him.

Comment: How about Whis?

Comment: @Luffy Unfortunately, even less is known about Whis, despite his being Beerus' master.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe beerus did know buu just didn't care about him only wanted pudding plus there's no real way to destroy buu so they could have met before and that's the reason buu didn't want to share his pudding cups, buu isn't really that self-centered, beerus could have beaten buu to a pulp once upon a time and that's how bibidi discovers him or beerus could have delegated his destroying responsibilities to him but I c this unlikely because kid buu seems unruly, proof that they met I believe is in the fact beerus knew to block his candy beam probably because he seen it before or it was used on him and also beerus is forgetful, all the ancient people n the universe knew buu and feared him and beerus from king cold to the kias

Answer (score 0):

Majin Buu or Kid Buu was stronger than Beerus 75 million years ago, so even if Beerus knew about him, he'd be helpless against him. Beerus attained his strength by training with Whis for 75-85 million years.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that they have met before.  And you who are saying Buu is indestructible, he kind of is.  If they battled for millions of years, eventually Buu would win.  Remember when Beerus fought Goku, used one super move, and then after that he had run out of energy.  If Buu, and I am talking kid Buu, has instant transmission, he could teleport away and have Beerus without any energy left.  Goku only did not teleport away because then it would have hit the Earth.  Kid Buu could not have cared less about if the Earth or any planet was destroyed. He destroys planets.

Comment: SSJ3 Goku was fighting on par with kid buu but got one shot by Beerus who didn't even break a sweat. I think it's safe to say Beerus could have completely destroyed kid Buu in an instant, as he did with Zamasu.